# UITouch movement speed detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to detect the speed of touch movement and i'm not always getting the results I'd expect. ***(added: Speed spikes around too much)*** Can anyone spot if i'm doing something funky or suggest a better way of doing it ?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.previousTimestamp = event.timestamp;
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat distanceFromPrevious = distanceBetweenPoints(location,prevLocation);
    NSTimeInterval timeSincePrevious = event.timestamp - self.previousTimestamp;
    CGFloat speed = distanceFromPrevious/timeSincePrevious;
    self.previousTimestamp = event.timestamp;
    NSLog(@"dist %f | time %f | speed %f",distanceFromPrevious, timeSincePrevious, speed);

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try (zero out distanceSinceStart and timeSinceStart in touchesBegan):

```
distanceSinceStart = distanceSinceStart + distanceFromPrevious;
timeSinceStart = timeSincestart + timeSincePrevious;
speed = distanceSinceStart/timeSinceStart;
```

which will give you the average speed since you started the touch (total distance/total time).

Or you could do a moving average of the speed, perhaps an exponential moving average:

```
const float lambda = 0.8f; // the closer to 1 the higher weight to the next touch

newSpeed = (1.0 - lambda) * oldSpeed + lambda* (distanceFromPrevious/timeSincePrevious);
oldSpeed = newSpeed;
```

You can adjust lambda to values near 1 if you want to give more weight to recent values.

Comment: Hey... i'm having trouble implementing this.  Is lambda function part of objective-c ?  What do I need to implement it ?   tia

Comment: Nope...it's a constant you specify yourself.  The closer it is to 1, the more weight you place on the newest value.  Compare to an arithmetic average of n values.  Each new value gets a weight of 1/n.

For exponential, set lambda = 2/(n+1) where n is the equivalent arithmetic value.  So the new value is weighted 2/(n+1) instead of 1/n, and then the existing moving average is scaled back by (1-lambda) = (n-1)/(n+1) and the two are added.

Clearer?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that the speed calculation will be very *inaccurate* when `timeSincePrevious` is very small (a few milliseconds). To see this, let's say that `timeSincePrevious` is 1ms. Then the calculated speed will be 0 if the `distanceFromPrevious` is 0, and 1000 if the `distanceFromZero` is 1.

For this reason I suggest the following value of lambda:

> ```
> const float labmda = (timeSincePrevious>0.2? 1: timeSincePrevious/0.2);
> ```

That is to say, we use a tiny lambda when the `timeSincePrevious` is small.

Comment: This is the only answer using a proper variable sample rate filter. And to do it like a standard first-order low-pass:
    k = <response time>;
    a = exp(-dt / k);
    filteredSpeed = a * (dx / dt) + (1-a) * filteredSpeed;

Answer (score 1):

The filter suggestion might be ok, but it doesn't solve the problem: the peak will be smoothed out, but remain.

If you logged out the touch events, these peaks will look like a touch with very little time delta from previous (0.001215 ms), preceding by touch with large time delta.

```
distance = 17.269917, timeDelta = 0.016132, speed = 1070.504639 
distance = 15.206906, timeDelta = 0.017494, speed = 869.251709 
distance = 15.882380, timeDelta = 0.017583, speed = 903.297546 
distance = 14.983324, timeDelta = 0.030101, speed = 497.771088      //low peak
distance = 15.435349, timeDelta = 0.001215, speed = 12703.991211    //high peak!
distance = 15.882380, timeDelta = 0.017343, speed = 915.795898 
distance = 15.890248, timeDelta = 0.016302, speed = 974.742249 
distance = 16.560495, timeDelta = 0.016468, speed = 1005.606445 
distance = 16.101242, timeDelta = 0.017291, speed = 931.201050
```

What I do is compute an average time delta between recent touch events, and if there is a touch with abnormal time delta (±30%), I ignore its speed (keeping the speed of the previous event)