# UITapGestureRecognizer only fires when state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded

Tags: uitapgesturerecognizer

I've added a UITapGestureRecognizer to my UIView:

[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)] autorelease]];

It seems to work fine, except that it doesn't fire until the finger(s) is/are released from the screen, i.e. when the tap recognizer's state is UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.  I need to know in real time when the finger first touches the screen as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up

Comment: Oh yes, answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up.  Glad to know it's possible!