# iOS Combining longPress and swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c

1. I add a swipeUp gesture to the whole view.
2. I add a longPressGestureRecognizer to the whole view, set its minimunPressDuration equals 0.001f so that it can both detect press down action and touches move action, then call the requireGestureToFail function:

> ```
>  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
>  longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.001f; 
>  [longPressGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGestureRecognizer];
> ```

**The problem is:**

When user press and hold (don't move) a button, the longPress gesture's state remains UIGestureStatePossible because the swipeUp gesture doesn't fail, So that it won't react to user touch.

If I don't call requireGestureRecognizerToFail all the gesture including swipeUp gesture will be recognised as longPress gesture.

Implmenting shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: is not what I expect.

What I want is when press and hold(don't move) a button, it triggers longPress, then if user swipe up it triggers swipeUp gesture, if user drags but the touch pattern doesn't fit swipeUp it still triggers longPress.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried reversing it? Maybe the swipe should require the long press to fail.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Still, all the gesture is recognised as longPress.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to implement your own UIGestureRecognizer or UIView subclass with multiple gestures. Check this out:

[UITapGestureRecognizer - make it work on touch down, not touch up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2