# Gesture recognizers and SceneKit

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, scenekit

Is there any way to catch touches (touchdowns, touchups etc) of individual meshes, or really `SCNNode`s, in SceneKit?

Answer (score 3):

An answer is in the SceneKit game template... :^)
In handleTap:, there is an example on how to use `hitTest:options:` which is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the default SceneKit game template in Xcode you will see code that allows you do recognize if a node got touched. In viewDidLoad write the following code...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(customMehtod:)];
NSMutableArray *gestureRecognizers = [NSMutableArray array];
[gestureRecognizers addObject:tapGesture];
[gestureRecognizers addObjectsFromArray:scnView.gestureRecognizers];
scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers;
```

Now create the custom method with the following code inside:

```
-(void)boardTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognize
{

 // check what nodes are tapped
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognize locationInView:scnView];
NSArray *hitResults = [scnView hitTest:p options:nil];

if([hitResults count] > 0){
    SCNHitTestResult *result = [hitResults objectAtIndex:0];
    if(result.node == myNode){
       //do something...
    }
}
```

And thats it! put whatever node you want in the if statement: if(result.node == myNode).

Answer (score -2):

touchDown is best achieved using a longPress gesture with a very short duration, unless you want to override the touches.

Answered before: [UITapGestureRecognizer - make it work on touch down, not touch up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up)

And the hit test works once you grab the x/y position of the tap and hitTest it.  ( see the Xcode boilerplate code for this )