# Change Color of UICollectionViewCell on touch

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an array of cells in a collection view that I want to get to act like buttons.

When I tap on one, I want that cell to highlight, and then change colors.

I'm able to initially set the color of the view.backgroundColor inside of the collectionViewCell us the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. However, contrary to what I thought would work if I do this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: ButtonCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ButtonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ButtonCollectionCell
    cell.cellBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
}
```

the color still isn't changing...

Essentially I want these cells to behave exactly like a button. I want them to highlight to a lighter gray color upon touch (they are initially white) after I release my finger I want them to become a dark gray color.

If I touch again I want them to again highlight to a lighter gray color, and then become white again.

If `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` isn't the way to do it, what is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend some changes in your code that will help you to resolve your error.

First I would call the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method to get your `cell` instead of using the `dequeue` method:

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ButtonCollectionCell
```

Then you should call the `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` inside the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method to reload the cell:

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
```

Also you shouldn't change the background in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method, but in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method where you check if the cell is selected:

```
if(cell?.selected){
  //set your background-color
}else{
  //change color
}
```

Comment: the reloadItemsAtIndexPaths and change of cellForItemAtIndexPath worked in so much that I can change the color of the cell when I press on it if the background is changed within the didSelectItemAtIndexPath.. it is no working with the `if(cell.selected) statement. The cells don't respond to anything I tell them to do in the if cell selected statement

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own touch down gesture recognizer for the `UICollectionView`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15629234/1557276

When it's done, call `-indexPathForItemAtPoint:` method of the `UICollectionView` instance and then make changes in the cell returned by `-cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 1):

When you `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` it can return a new cell to you.

Instead use `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to get the current cell at that index path.

Comment: I'm using the `dequeue` method because I'm running into an optional unwrapping nil error when I use `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Any ideas how to fix this? @thelaws

Comment: Presumably this is because `cellForItemAtIndexPath` will return `nil` for cells that are offscreen. You just need to properly check if the Optional is nil before trying to set the background colour of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code I your method:

```
collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
```