# How do I make a function that executes when a tap gesture is lifted in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Is there any way that i can setup a tapGestureRecognizer in an iOS app, that either sends a signal both when an object is tapped, ***and*** when the tap is released, or setup up two tapGestureRecognizer's, one that handles the tap, and one that handles the release?

My tapGestureRecognizer is initialized like this:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TapInToSubView))
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    sender.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Hope someone out there can help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up

Comment: A Tap is a tap. You are probably looking for UIGestureRecognizer state .began, .changed, .ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer) . Set the minimumPressDuration and You can then handle the gesture state methods :

```
(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
```

etc. and fire your actions accordingly.

> Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins (began) when
>   the number of allowable fingers (numberOfTouchesRequired) have been
>   pressed for the specified period (minimumPressDuration) and the
>   touches do not move beyond the allowable range of movement
>   (allowableMovement). The gesture recognizer transitions to the Change
>   state whenever a finger moves, and it ends (ended) when any of the
>   fingers are lifted.

Comment: @LeoDabus Why not ? If you have a better solution, post it .

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer would be enough for what the OP is asking

Comment: @LeoDabus UILongPressGestureRecognizer is a subclass of UIGestureRecognizer and does not make a difference. However, having it as a UILongPressGestureRecognizer you can set up multiple different recognizers on the same view and make it more clean and easy. You can for example still add a UITapGestureRecognizer simulataniously. If you think this does not answer the question or is not a solution/good solution, You can add your UIGestureRecognizer as an answer and the OP and readers will have multiple choises to chose from.

Comment: @LeoDabus This solves the question and still allows a tapGesture to be added simultaniously if needed without any mess. As I said, a UILongPressGestureRecognizer is a SUBCLASS of UIGestureRecognizer. If you want to post your methods with UIGestureRecognizer do it, so people can see the different options and upvote yours instead!!

Comment: "BTW the minimum time OP would have to wait is 0.5 sec", this is the DEFAULT VALUE. NOT THE MINIMUM. the MINIMUM VALUE is 0.