# Multiple UITapGestureRecognizer not working on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to add multiple `UITapGestureRecognizer` on `UIScrollView` but it recognise only one gesture.
I want to add first gesture for touch begin and second one for touch end event.

Following is my code:-

```
self.tapStartGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
self.tapStartGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
self.tapStartGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.tapStartGesture setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan];
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapStartGesture];

self.tapEndGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
self.tapEndGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
self.tapEndGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapEndGesture];

- (void)tapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if(sender==self.tapStartGesture) {
        NSLog(@"tapStartGesture");
    } else if(sender==self.tapEndGesture) {
        NSLog(@"tapEndGesture");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tap gesture only has one state - "ended". You can't detect when a tap starts using a tap gesture. As you've seen, attempting to use two tap gestures doesn't accomplish what you want.

You need to implement the `UIResponder` methods `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`.

You may also want to see [UITapGestureRecognizer - make it work on touch down, not touch up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up)
.

Comment: Every time recognizing *tapEndGesture*. tapStartGesture is not call

Comment: Oh right. A tap gesture only has the one state. It''s only a tap gesture if, at the end, it has been recognized as an actual tap. You can't get a "began" state for a tap gesture. If you want to know when a user touches the screen and again when they stop touching the screen, look into overriding the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods from `UIResponder`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by implement custom gesture.

**File:-MyGesture.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyGesture : UIGestureRecognizer
@end
```

**File:-MyGesture.m**

```
#import "MyGesture.h"
@implementation MyGesture    
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {;
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
}    
@end
```

> How to Use:-

```
MyGesture *gesture = [[MyGesture alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myGesture:)];
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

- (void)myGesture:(MyGesture *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"tapStartGesture");
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"tapEndGesture");
    }
}
```