# How to effectively process UITouches in a multitouch sequence

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uitouch, uibezierpath, uiresponder

I am working with multitouch while writing, So basically what I am doing is, I am writing with hand support, because typically, its how user writes, I followed this link [How to ignore certain UITouch Points in multitouch sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853765/how-to-ignore-certain-uitouch-points-in-multitouch-sequence)

Everything is working fine with single touch, but their is some problem when I write with my hand touching the screen i.e multiple UItouches
Below is my code

In touches began, I go through all touches  and I find the touch with highest y position, below is my code

Below is my code

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* topmostTouch = self.trackingTouch;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        ctr = 0;

        touchStartPoint1 = [touch locationInView:self];


        if(!topmostTouch || [topmostTouch locationInView:self].y > touchStartPoint1.y)
        {
            topmostTouch = touch;
            pts[0] = touchStartPoint1;
        }
    }   

    self.trackingTouch = topmostTouch;
}
```

In touches moved., I will only take self.trackingTouch, which I found in touches Began

My touches Moved code below

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    if(self.trackingTouch== nil)
    {
        return;
    }

    CGPoint p = [self.trackingTouch locationInView:self];
    ctr++;
    pts[ctr] = p;

    if (ctr == 4)
    {
        pts[3] = midPoint(pts[2], pts[4]);

        self.currentPath = [[DrawingPath alloc] init];

        [self.currentPath setPathColor:self.lineColor];
        self.currentPath.pathWidth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.lineWidth];


        [self.currentPath.path moveToPoint:pts[0]];
        [self.currentPath.path addCurveToPoint:pts[3] controlPoint1:pts[1] controlPoint2:pts[2]];

        [self setNeedsDisplay];


        pts[0] = pts[3];
        pts[1] = pts[4];
        ctr = 1;
    }
}
```

For your reference here is the image of writing with single touch and multitouch respectively

[image]

[image]

You can see that, when I write with single touch, my writing is smooth, the curves are smooth, but when I write with hand resting, I curves get jagged, as you can see in the second image.

So friends, please help me out

Comment: I think, something is going wrong with tracking touch, and thats why it is messing with it

Comment: Perhaps you could try to detect the location of the user's resting hand, and disable touches in that area?  Once the user starts drawing, why not just ignore any touches not near that touch before `touchesEnded:` and `touchesCancelled:`?

Comment: Hello @AaronBrager, thanks for replying, as you can see , I am already finding the tracking touch and ignoring the rest of the touches based on higher value of y, in touches began. Do you mean the same thing by ignoring near touches before touchesEnded: and touchesCancelled: Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the drawing code is all the same the difference is only the extra overhead of processing the extra touches.  Looping to process these, looping to draw, everything is at least doubled..  So while you are processing touch and then drawing on finger #2, out here in the real world finger #1 etc is/are still moving... Be mindful that UIKit can only draw at the end of each runLoop.  I don't think there is any way around this, also as I told you before, I doubt there are many people who will value the ability to draw with multiple touches, although this may well be my limited, English speaking, Australian perspective on it.  Good luck

Comment: Hello @Jef, thanks for your reply, You are right, we need to intelligently process those extra touches, and user will rest his hand on the screen and write, we cannot expect the user to write on the screen without resting his hand , as he/she typically take notes, so according to me, this is an important issue which needs to be adressed.

Comment: Hello @Jef, I think the problem is in touchesBegan: function. What say?

Comment: Hello @Jef, please help me out with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033228/eraser-the-drawing-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue,

Here is the code

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* topmostTouch = self.trackingTouch;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {


        touchStartPoint1 = [touch locationInView:self];


        if(!topmostTouch || [topmostTouch locationInView:self].y > touchStartPoint1.y)
        {
            ctr = 0;
            topmostTouch = touch;
            pts[0] = touchStartPoint1;
        }
    }   

    self.trackingTouch = topmostTouch;
}
```

The problem was very simple, just set ctr = 0 , inside the check, like this..