# Swift Get Direction of Swipe Gesture

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a UIButton in Swift with the following code:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: "tileSwiped:", forControlEvents: .TouchDragExit)
```

My tileSwiped function definition is as follows:

```
func tileSwiped(button: UIButton) {
}
```

What I would like to do is determine which direction the TouchDragExit event occurred in. More specifically, my button is a rectangle, and I would like to know if the drag exited on the top, bottom, left, or right edge of the rectangle.

However, I don't see a way to do this without having access to the motion event that triggered the function call. But of course, I can't change the parameters passed to the tileSwiped function. So how can I get the direction of the "swipe"?

(I'm open to changing my approach to listening for the gesture because I don't think this approach will get me anywhere, but note that I do need to keep the button as a parameter.)

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10272055/4272498

Comment: If you have array of buttons,how can you set the frame for each button?From above your code I understand only finding direction using swipe gesture recognizer.Post the code clearly.

Comment: Today I am on leave.So tomorrow I bring the solution for your question.

Comment: kmell96 are you there?

Comment: I am here to help you.If you tell the concept clearly I am ready to give the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your offer to help. However, I was able to solve my problem using the information provided below by averello and the additions I specified in my comment on his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, see [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html).

What you want to do is:

1. Create a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`
2. Specify which direction you want to recognize
3. Add this recognizer to the button
4. Implement the callback method

Example:

```
let button = UIButton();
// 1
let swipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:");
// 2
swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = .Left
// 3
button.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)
```

.

```
// 4
func swipe(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    NSLog("left")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work in my case because I have an array of UIButtons and the action I perform has to change based on which button is swiped. In other words, I would need the UIButton to be passed to the swipe function as a parameter as well.

Comment: Was able to build on your answer to get one that works for me. The UISwipeGestureRecognizer has a property called "view" that gives you the button associated with it. You have to do: (gestureRecognizer.view as? UIButton)!